# Unable to find a simple grails framework like scaffolding for Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, code-generation, scaffolding

I have picked up laravel again after some years and now I am running version `5.6`. So being introduced to scaffolding the first time by grails, it looks I am strongly influenced by its simplicity.

I am looking for a similar scaffolding generation "system" that will pick my Eloquent Models or migration files and generate:

- CRUD Views
- Controllers and CRUD methods

I have been doing some googling based on what I know of quick admin generators. I found a comparison of [13 admin generators on laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/13-laravel-admin-panel-generators) and I believe they are all kind of all out proposing a bit too much fully loaded features than I need right now. Please don't get me wrong they are all nice and I think might try voyager in another tries when I have fully grasped laravel.

I also have spatie/permission installed already and some of the admin generators seem to come packaged with their own permission/auth packages.

Has any of you come across anything simple that I can leverage on? Thanks in advance.